# Docusign Tabs not showing up in the envelope created from Template

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on Embedded signing and trying to create an envelope from a template.
After I create the envelope and create a signing URL(This logic works fine). But when I click the signing URL I see no Tabs in the document to sign. I have to drag and drop the tabs(as a Signer).

The template is simple with One recipient with a role (Without name and email).

```
public class EmbeddedSigningController {

@AuraEnabled
public static String sendEnvelope(String[] template, String[] description, Id recordId, String memberId, String memberEmail, String memberRId, String memberName) {
  try {

      List<dfsle.Document> docs = new List<dfsle.Document>();
      for(Integer i=0; i < template.size(); i++) {
        docs.add(dfsle.Document.fromTemplate(dfsle.UUID.parse(template[i]), description[i]));
      }
      dfsle.CustomField CustField = new dfsle.CustomField('text', '##SFCase', recordId, null, true, true);
      dfsle.Envelope dsEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(
        new dfsle.Entity(recordId))
        .withDocuments(docs)
        .withCustomFields(new List<dfsle.CustomField> { CustField })
        .withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> { dfsle.Recipient.newEmbeddedSigner(memberName, memberEmail, memberRId) }
      );

      dsEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(dsEnvelope, true );
      System.debug('EnvelopeId: ' + String.valueOf(dsEnvelope.docuSignId));



      PlatformEventService pes = new PlatformEventService();
      Boolean record = pes.createMbrDocusignEnvelopeEvent(recordId, String.valueOf(dsEnvelope.docuSignId), memberId, memberEmail);

      if(record == false) {
        throw new EmbeddedSigningException('Error Creating Platform Event');
      }

      return String.valueOf(dsEnvelope.docuSignId);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
      System.debug('Error in catch: ' + e.getMessage());
      return e.getMessage();
    }

}

  @AuraEnabled
  public static Boolean voidEnvelope(String envelopeId, String reason) {
    Boolean isVoided = dfsle.StatusService.voidEnvelope(dfsle.UUID.parse(envelopeId), reason);
    System.debug('isVoided: ' + isVoided);
    return isVoided;
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't see the templateRole anywhere. What is the name of the role? do you pass it anywhere?

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Inbar is correct, you need to specify which `role` in the template the signer is fulfilling. Also, why are you specifying a document if you're using a template?

See my [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/use-template-luke) for a full discussion of using templates. It includes links to live examples you can try out via the API Request Builder.

Here's a quick example of setting a role with C#:

```
    // Create the envelope request and send it to DocuSign
    // Returns the resulting envelopeId or ""
    static string SendDocuSignEnvelope()
    {
        TemplateRole templateRole1 = new TemplateRole
        {
            Email = null,  
            Name = null,  
            RoleName = "signer1" 
        };
        TemplateRole templateRole2 = new TemplateRole
        {
            Email = null,  
            Name = null,  
            RoleName = "signer2" 
        };
        List<TemplateRole> templateRoles1 = new List<TemplateRole> {templateRole1, templateRole2};
        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
        {
            Status = "sent",  
            TemplateId = "61973947-7d29-490d-9bac-5fa05846b10e",  
            TemplateRoles = templateRoles1 
        };

        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
        apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
        try
        {
            EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
            Console.WriteLine($"Envelope status: {results.Status}. Envelope ID: {results.EnvelopeId}");
            return results.EnvelopeId;
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception while creating envelope!");
            Console.WriteLine($"Code: {e.ErrorCode}\nContent: {e.ErrorContent}");
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return "";
        }
    }
```